# get_object_or_404 inherited classes

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a abstract class `Type` and it have 3 inherited classes `Type1 Type2 Type3` 70% of these 3 class properties are the same.

i want like this;

```
Tip=get_object_or_404(Type,tournament__slug=tournamentslug,slug=slug,game__slug=gameslug,)
```

However Type is abstract class i cannot get object or filter

views.py (now)

```
def game_detail(request,tournamentslug,slug,gameslug):
        tip1=get_object_or_404(Type1, tournament__slug=tournamentslug,slug=slug,game__slug=gameslug,)
        tip2=get_object_or_404(Type2,tournament__slug=tournamentslug,slug=slug,game__slug=gameslug,)
        tip3=get_object_or_404(Type3,tournament__slug=tournamentslug,slug=slug,game__slug=gameslug,)
```

Comment: I didn't get the question. You want to verify if _tournamentslug, slug and gameslug_ are fields of `Type` (the base abstract class)!?

Comment: yes i want like ;         Tip=get_object_or_404(Type,tournament__slug=tournamentslug,slug=slug,game__slug=gameslug,) However Type is abstract class i cannot get object or filter

Comment: If `Type` is abstract, it is not backed by any table, so, from where `get_object_or_404(Type,...)` would fetch its values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix those 3 models, because they are a different models and different tables in database. You need to create your own `get_object_or_404` what accepts queryset, and input there a mixed queryset,
or test all 3 models separately and raise 404 by yourself when there's no any object.

Or if 70% of data in this classes are that same, maybe you can just keep them all using one big model? Just merge Type1 Type2 Type3 to one universal Type model. IMO it's more reasonable than creating 3 similar models with number inside the name

Comment: Type1 have extra 5 fields Type2 have extra 3 fields.. Also Type1 xxx=models.ForeignKey(). Therefore, Type2 xxx=models.ManytoManyField. I did this so it wasn't complicated.

Comment: However, i'll think about it to merge

Comment: You can merge the models but the problem is if the merged model would represent your data as it would, is really hard to tell without knowing anything about it. Is okay to fetch data from type2 when you look for type1?

Comment: I did the abstract class because it was very complex.I'll combine and see what happens.